# How can a class see a public member of another class when the member is a private class instance

Tags: java

I am a C++ programmer trying to understand best practices of the Java language. Please tailor your responses accordingly :)

I worked out an example and I don't understand why/how the behavior I observed is possible.

```
//HelloWorld.java

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Newfile nf = new Newfile();
        nf.setTest(5);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(nf.test.i));
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

//Newfile.java

class TEST {
    public int i;
}

public class Newfile{    
    public TEST test = new TEST();
    public int setTest(int i) {
        return test.i = i;
    }
}

// THIS WORKED 
/*
   5
   Hello World
*/
```

Since `Test` is private (well I presume) then how can `HelloWorld` even manipulate the contents of `TEST` (i.e. the `i` member)?

Now the strange part, when I moved `TEST` to a private inner class of `Newfile` it now behave as I would've expected the above experiment to behave and I got:

```
i in Newfile.TEST is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
```

Comment: `Test` is package-private on not completly private. This means it can be accessed by contents in the same package. (I assume they are in one package)

Comment: Downvoter, please care to explain? Downvoting, has become so random that it has lost its value. The question, is clear, concise, not a homework (obviously). When you do find a question easy, or obvious, well, that doesn't mean it's a bad one.

Comment: not the downvoter, but you could argure that there is no reasearch effort. You assume that it´s private without researching if it´s actually the case.

Comment: If that's a valid argument, then all stackoverflow questions should be downvoted. One way or another, every question, if you knew where/what to look for, can be researched and self-answered. I am very new to Java, concepts like these, if I knew they existed, I would obviously have researched them. I was trying to map the concept of anonymous namespace (that exists in C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since `TEST` is `private` (well I presume)

Nope. It's actually `package-private`.

From [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package

---

**EDIT**

Both your `HelloWorld` and your `TEST` classes are members of the same package (in your case, since you don't appear to have specified the package explicitly, they are members of the unnamed package). Therefore, even though `TEST` is package-private, it is accessible from `HelloWorld`.

> Now the strange part, when I moved TEST to a private inner class of
>   Newfile it now behave as I would've expected the above experiment to
>   behave and I got:
>
> ```
> i in Newfile.TEST is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
> ```

By making`TEST` a `private` inner class of `Newfile` you make it accessible only to members of `Newfile` class itself, so, naturally, it's no longer accessible from `HelloWorld` in this case.

Comment: I am not able to assign it specifically as private, why is this so?

Comment: Classes _(**EDIT**: with the exception of inner classes)_ in Java can either be explicitly declared `public` or have no access specifier at all (thus being package-private). A question: if there _was_ a `private` specifier for classes (there isn't), what exactly would you expect it to mean?

Comment: @TerraPass only partitially true, inner classes can be private.

Comment: when I declare TEST as private (not as an inner class), I get `error: modifier private not allowed here`. Why am I not allowed to make it private?

Comment: @KevinEsche Yes, my bad. I was referring to classes at package level.

Comment: @Kam Again, your `Test` class is not an inner class, it's declared at package level. "Package-private" already means that only classes in the same package have access to it. What exactly would `private` even mean for a class in this case?

Comment: It would mean private, only the current Java file. I am trying to equate this to a anonymous namespace in C++. What you are saying is that this is simply not possible.

Comment: @Kam Right. There is no access specifier in Java, which means "accessible only from this file".